# Is there a way to get the value inside the table by clicking an HREF Link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, html, json

I am reading a JSON file, accessed via Python. The values from JSON file will be then displayed on a table. Per row, I have a button. What I want is to see the value when I click the button.

What algorithm I could use in such a way that i could store the ALL values so when I click the button, I can get its corresponding ROW value.

Iteration of my JSON file below:

```
<tr>
    <td align="center">{{ entryIteration.sha1 }}</td>
    <td align="center">{{ entryIteration.requestedStatus }}</td>
    <td align="center">{{ entryIteration.detectionName }}</td>
    <td>{{ entryIteration.userRemarks }}</td>
    <td>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalApprove">Approve</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalReject">Reject</a>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">View</a>
    </td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.btn btn-default').click(function(){
    var tdtext1 = $(this).closest('tr').find('.tdclass1')
     var tdtext2 = $(this).closest('tr').find('.tdclass2')
})
```

Use [.closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) to get the value of data in the row where the button is

> Description: For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree.